# How can I make a java applet connect with a server?

Tags: java, sockets, applet

Please excuse my noobishness as I am teaching myself Java and don't know a lot.

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game that runs from Java applets, I have a server-side program working that will accept strings of text, but all my attempts to find code for applets have failed.

My best attempt looks like it works but I think fails to connect to the server, any ideas why? (localIP is my correct IP and works fine in other tests)

```
public void init()
{
   try
   {
       socket = new Socket(localIP, 5555);
       inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
       outStream = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
   never reached
   }
}
```

I don't mind scrapping this if someone can tell me a better way to do it or any way at all.

Comment: `but I think fails to connect to the server,` what exactly happens when you run this code?

Comment: The program fails to give any errors and runs as if it has worked, the server doesn't pick up on anything either.

Answer (score 0):

a java applet can only connect to the server from which it was downloaded.  if you are not loading the applet from `localIP`, then you will not be able to connect to it.

you may be able to get around this restriction by signing the applet.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are not using the Http Protocol, One assumes that the applet is loaded from another port other than 5555. If this is the case, the applet needs to be signed in order to do this functionality.

Comment: Taking what you both said this seams imposable, the web page will naturally be on port 80 which will already be bound by my web hosting program, how can I have a server run on the same port?
Or is there a way to fake this?

Comment: add a servlet that handles some context that the applet will communicate through. The Applet will use HttpURLConnection (and the HttpProtocol) to do Http Get or Http Posts from the applet.

Comment: if your hosting company doesn't support java server based coding, and you are just loading applets from it, and then connecting to a different server, then you can still do it, the applet just needs to be signed, which you can do yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and complete response, even though it's bad news for me.